# What does the output of `showq -r -u <username>` mean?

Tags: linux, bash, process, cluster, job-control

On a cluster, I did

```
showq -r -u matthey
```

where `matthey` is my username. Here is the output

```
active jobs------------------------
JOBID               S  PAR  EFFIC  XFACTOR  Q  USERNAME    ACCNT            MHOST PROCS   REMAINING            STARTTIME

7056827[219]        R  DDR  99.01      1.5 no   matthey hkw-282-           pod1b2     1    14:00:25  Thu Aug  4 23:22:45
7056827[226]        R  DDR 100.00      1.9 no   matthey hkw-282-          pod1b16     1  1:00:47:27  Fri Aug  5 10:09:47
7056827[225]        R  DDR 100.00      1.9 no   matthey hkw-282-           pod3b2     1  1:00:47:27  Fri Aug  5 10:09:47

3 active jobs            3 of 9048 processors in use by local jobs (0.03%)
                        866 of 869 nodes active      (99.65%)
```

Can you please explain to me the meaning of each of these columns?

I understand the meaning of `JOBID`, `USERNAME`, `PROCS`, `REMAINING` and `STARTTIME` but the other columns are very much unclear to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find some explanation about showq in its man page by typing: `man showq`.
Citing from there:

`S`: Job State. Either "R" for Running or "S" for Starting

`PAR`: Partition in which job is running

`EFFIC`: CPU efficiency of job

`XFACTOR`: Current expansion factor of job, where XFactor = (QueueTime + WallClockLimit) / WallClockLimit

`Q`: Quality Of Service specified for job

`MHOST`: Master Host running primary task of job